# An Enigmatic Game

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, chess, retrograde-analysis

I have a fun-ky puzzle for everyone today.

Here is the position.

[image]

FEN-rnbq1rkb/ppp1pp2/5p2/8/8/4K3/PPPPNP1P/RNBQ1R2

It can be reached in one way in exactly 9.5 moves, or 10 White and 9 Black moves. However, there is a catch. A rule of chess must be broken in order for there to be a solution in time.

**Task:** Find the unique sequence of moves and state the broken rule.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can reach the position in the allotted number of moves by either

> temporarily ignoring check

or

by underpromoting a pawn

> to a pawn

Sequence of moves is essentially the same in both cases:

> [FEN ""]
>  1.g4 d5 2.g5 d4 3.g6 d3 4.gxh7 dxe2 5.hxg8=N exf1=P 6.Nf6+ gxf6 7.Ke2 Bg7
>  8.Ke3 O-O 9.Ne2 Bh8 10.Rxf1 *

[Replay](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/926/24424)

Answer (score 6):

This may not be the intended solution, but it does follow all the instructions:

> 1.  e4  d5
>   2.  g4  Nf6
>   3.  g5  dxe4
>   4.  gxf6    gxf6
>   5.  Bd3 Bg7
>   6.  Bxe4    0-0
>   7.  Bxh7    Kxh7
>   8.  Ke3 Kg8
>   9.  Ne2 Bh8
>   10. Rf1

> In this solution, the broken rule is that the king can only move one square, since it moves two squares in 8. Ke3. I recognize this may be a liberal interpretation of "broken rule", since I would normally interpret a broken rule as, for example, castling through check or castling after king/rook has moved, but this was the best I could do.

Comment: But the problem says the position "can be reached in one way". If the king can move two squares, is this solution unique? (Maybe it is. I haven't tried. But it's up to the person proposing a solution to show it is.)

Comment: @JohnBrookfields `0-0` is the official notation, cf. https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018